# DJANGO: How to return a HTML text?

Tags: python, html, django

My Code:

file views.py:

```
def z(request):
    htmltext = "hello <br><br> bye!"
    return render_to_response('base.html', {'htmltext' : htmltext})
```

file main.html:

```
<html>
.
.
.
<div id="content">

{{htmltext}}

</div>
.
.
.
</html>
```

MY PROBLEM: as response I get this text in my html page (content):

```
hello <br><br> bye!
```

but i want:

```
hello

bye!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potentially unsafe way to so this is to change your html code to be `{{htmltext|safe}}` however, depending on how the string is generated in your Python code, could lead to attacks on your website that inject arbitrary code into your HTML page.

The better option would be to put the HTML code `<br>` in the HTML file, so use something like `{{foo}}<br><br>{{bar}}`

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps me. But its sounds not good... is there a ohter alternative thats safer? I get a json file from an API. In this json file i have a large text with with html symbols like <br>.